# With whom you Spoke, or With whom you spoke with?

Tags: adjective-phrases

Example:

Mark, with whom you spoke at the party, will be joining us.

or is it

Mark, with whom you spoke with at the party, will be....

Answer (score 3):

***Mark, with whom you spoke at the party, will be joining us.*** is correct. The extra *with* is ungrammatical.  You may also hear the common but technically incorrect ***Mark, who you spoke with at the party, will be joining us.***, but notice that even in that incorrect form, the word *with* is used only once.

Comment: But, "Mark, whom you spoke with at the party ..." would offend some pedants but most would consider valid. It has no surplus words and the meaning is clear. Not saying it's better than "with whom you spoke".

Comment: @Jay - but even that form only uses ***with*** once, which was the main error in the querent's sentence.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, no disagreement there.